# After implementing Spring Session Management Spring security keeps forwarding me to the login page

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

I am working on JEE application.  We recently switched from container based security to spring security.   I am now trying move session handling out of the container and into the application using spring-session-jdbc.  I've created the required tables in our database and created the following SessionConfig file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

  @Bean
  public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    bean.setJndiName("java:jboss/MyDS");
    bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
    bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
  }

  @Bean
  public FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<?> sessionRepository(PlatformTransactionManager txManager,
      DataSource dataSource) {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    TransactionTemplate txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
    return new JdbcIndexedSessionRepository(jdbcTemplate, txTemplate);
  }

}
```

We have a security config where I autowire the the sessionRepository and use it to create the SessionAuthenticationStrategy like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

  @Autowired
  public FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<?> repo;

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    // put all static resource or external urls here
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/external/**", "/react/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/css/**",
        "/vendor/**", "/fonts/**");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    String maxSessions =
        GenericPropertiesReader.getInstance().getValue("config.logins.max.sessions");

    http.sessionManagement()// set the session management
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
        .invalidSessionUrl("/login.html") // no user session forward here
        .maximumSessions(Integer.valueOf(maxSessions))// 1 or -1 for unlimited
        .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)// new session will terminate old session and forward them
                                        // to the log in page
        .expiredUrl("/login.html?type=expired-session");

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests()// put any antMatchers after this
        .antMatchers("/login.html").permitAll() // permit any login page
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin() // we are using form login
        .loginPage("/login.html") // show our custom login form
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login") // post to Spring's action URL so our custom auth provider is invoked                                    
        .successHandler(successHandler()).failureHandler(failureHandler())
         .permitAll() // so anyone can see it
        .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(new MyLogoutSuccessHandler())// our custom logout handler
        .invalidateHttpSession(true) // delete session, need more work??
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") // and get rid of that cookie so they can't auto-login again
        .permitAll()

        .and().x509().x509AuthenticationFilter(this.x509AuthFilter());
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(x509AuthProvider()).authenticationProvider(loginAuthProvider());
  }

  @Bean
  public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider x509AuthProvider() {
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(x509PreAuthUserDetailsService());
    return provider;
  }

  @Bean // this irks me.
  public AuthenticationManager myAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return this.authenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  X509AuthenticationFilter x509AuthFilter() throws Exception {
    X509AuthenticationFilter filter = new X509AuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(x509SuccessHandler());
    filter.setPrincipalExtractor(x509Extractor());
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.myAuthenticationManager());
    filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler());
    return filter;
  }

  @Bean
  public X509PrincipalExtractor x509Extractor() {
    return new MyX509DodIdExtractor();
  }

  @Bean
  public MyX509PreAuthUserDetailsService x509PreAuthUserDetailsService() {
    return new MyX509PreAuthUserDetailsService();
  }

  @Bean
  public MyAuthenticationProvider loginAuthProvider() {
    return new MyAuthenticationProvider ();
  }

  @Bean
  MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler x509SuccessHandler() {
    MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler ();
    handler.setForwardResonse(false);
    return handler;
  }

  @Bean
  public MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
  }

  @Bean
  public MyAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
    MyAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler = new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    failureHandler.setExceptionMappings(LoginFailures.exceptionMap());
    failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login.html?login-failure=" + LoginFailures.DEFAULT.code);
    return failureHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<? extends Session> sessionRegistry()
      throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
    return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<>(repo);
  }

  @Bean
  public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy()
      throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
    ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy =
        new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
    return sessionAuthenticationStrategy;
  }
}
```

I see the session tables in the database being filled when attempting to login.  I never hit any of the authentication code when debugging.  I just am redirected to the login page every time.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious.   I was getting errors that there was no unique bean of type FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<?>  until I changed the name of the bean in SessionConfig to sessionRepository.  Which makes me think there's another bean of that type being instantiated by Spring (not in our code base) that might be interfering?

Comment: Try enabling trace logs with `-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=trace` to see what's triggering the redirect.

Comment: I didn't see any changes to the log, but I did notice some logging from org.jboss.security  "Setting security roles Threadlocal: null"  now I'm wondering if Jboss is interfering.